# Matter.js - How to add sprite texture to a constraint?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have a simple setup with matter.js with a touch point to interact with and a box hanging from it by a spring constraint. Imagine an object hanging by an elastic band, dangling off the end of your finger.

I don't know how to render the constraint in the way I want - to attach a sprite texture to it. I don't want a chain or an object constraint, as they don't have elasticity - I want the bounce of the spring constraint.

Is there a way to add a sprite image to a constraint? Or is there a soft body with elastic properties I've missed? I've been over the documentation but find it very hard to understand.

Comment: I will post for one two week with god help answer. Look at this project : https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visual-ts I already implement basic frame by frame ...

Comment: Can you clarify? If you have an example of the code working, can you post a snippet here? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by implementing a frame by frame solution - I'm using matter.js to solve physics on the fly, so can't use a frame by frame animation to render the spring constraint.

Comment: I would use a custom renderer. The built-in renderer is for prototyping purposes only.